# SPFX webpart Development

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am totally new to sharepoint SPFX webpart development. Now i need to develop a SPFX webpart to display sharepoint LIST and to add new items on the same sharepoint list.

I just created a sample hello wold webpart and published in Sharepoint.

Requesting to share few links to add sharepoint list items and to display sharepoint list on web part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pnp js.
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

SPFX demo with pnp js for your reference:

https://office365journey.com/sharepoint-framework-development-create-list-crud-webpart-using-pnp-js/